# Excel - Dynamic apply function to column

Tags: excel

I have the following setup in Excel:

```
Enter number of Kgs: 22


kgs     price
 0        80        
 5        120
 10       150
 15       165
 20       180
 25       190
 30       200
 35       300
```

So, based on which range cell D1 (Number of kgs) fall into, it will select the correct price. This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(D1<A3;C2;0)
```

So, if the amount of kgs is less than 5 `(A3)`, it will select the price with the value "80" `(C2)`.

I want to apply this to the entire row: for example, if the amount of kgs is 24, it will select 180 as a price and so on.

How can this be applied dynamically to the entire column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose the following formula:

```
=INDEX(B5:B12;MATCH(D1;A5:A12;1))
```

This is based on the assumption that the KGs are in in `A5:A12` and the prices are in `B5:B12`.

Note, that the `MATCH` formula is used with a 1 at the end. This indicates that the value being search must not be found in the list. Yet, the value closest to the search value (but smaller) will be returned. If you change the 1 to a -1 then it will return the value which is the closest (but larger) than the value searched.